# How I can know which type of gradient descent to use?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I understand the three types of gradient descent, but my problem is I can not know which type I must use on my model. I have read a lot, but I did not get it.

No code, it is just question.

Comment: What have you read? How far have you understood? What do you don't understand? Or at least what is the problem you want to solve with gradient descent?

Comment: "I don't get it" is not a Stack Overflow type of question.  The proper method to use depends on the model and input data -- and, at the most basic level, degenerates to the empirical question of what works best in your paradigm.  Since you haven't described your situation at all, this question is essentially a request for broad tutoring -- off topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types of Gradient Descent:

- **Batch Gradient Descent**: It processes all the training examples for each iteration of gradient descent. But, this method is computationally expensive when the number of training examples is large and usually not preferred.
- **Stochastic Gradient Descent**: It processes one training example in each iteration. Here, the parameters are being updated after each iteration. This method is faster than batch gradient descent method. But, it increases system overhead when number of training examples is large by increasing the number of iterations.
- **Mini Batch gradient descent**: Mini batch algorithm is the most favorable and widely used algorithm that makes precise and faster results using a batch of `m` training examples. In mini batch algorithm rather than using the complete data set, in every iteration we use a set of `m` training examples called `batch` to compute the gradient of the cost function. Common mini-batch sizes range between `50` and `256`, but can vary for different applications.

There are various other optimization algorithms apart from gradient descent variants, like adam, rmsprop, etc.

**Which optimizer should we use?**

The question was to choose the best optimizer for our Neural Network Model in order to converge fast and to learn properly and tune the internal parameters so as to minimize the Loss function.

> Adam works well in practice and outperforms other Adaptive techniques.

If your input data is sparse then methods such as `SGD`, `NAG` and `momentum` are inferior and perform poorly. For sparse data sets one should use one of the adaptive learning-rate methods. An additional benefit is that we won't need to adjust the learning rate but likely achieve the best results with the default value.

If one wants fast convergence and train a deep neural network Model or a highly complex Neural Network, then `Adam` or any other Adaptive learning rate techniques should be used because they outperforms every other optimization algorithms.

I hope this would help you to decide which one to use for your model.

Comment: i'm not totaly agree with bigger batch size = better accuracy for more computing time. From my small knowledge with CNN, batch size and learning rate are very important hyperparameter (so is optimizer). https://medium.com/mini-distill/effect-of-batch-size-on-training-dynamics-21c14f7a716e

Comment: Read it carefully its saying nothing about accuracy but generalization on unseen data. check this out for better comparison: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316464/how-does-batch-size-affect-convergence-of-sgd-and-why. And by the way above accuracy is on training data.

Comment: And yeah more thing accuracy doesn't only depends on batch size. There are other hyper-parameters. I removed the above diagram as it might be confusing for many. But, yeah I should have mentioned batch SD gives higher accuracy than mini batches in less number of epochs as the model has already seen all the training samples which is not the case with mini batch SD but it is computationally inefficient to perform.